# Positive integer solutions to product

Tags: markov-chains, diophantine-equations, integers

For $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$, I am looking for all positive integer solutions to
$$a(b+1)c(d+1)=(a+1)b(c+1)d.$$
I already figured out that $a=b$ and $c=d$ as well as $a=d$ and $b=c$. But now I am stuck and I am wondering how I can check for more solutions. How can I approach this?

The problem arises from considerations on a Markov chain $X$ associated to a particle system on a finite graph $G$. Solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ give subgraphs of  which are "of low energy" with respect to the stationary distribution of $X$.

Comment: Some families of solutions: $(u,u,v,v)$; $(u,v,v,u)$; $(u,u+1,w,u+2)$ with $w=(u+1)^2/(u-1)$ and $u -1 \mid 4$; $(u,u+1,w,2u+1)$ with $u -1 \mid 6$.

Comment: The group of symmetries is the subgroup of $S_4$ of order $8$ generated by $(ac)$ and $(abcd)$.

Comment: Could you give me a source which explains your second comment more in detail? I do not quite understand what "generated by $(ac)$ and $(abcd)$" means.

Comment: My observation on the group of symmetries is purely empirical but you can try all 24 permutations and see which work. For the notation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: One approach: defining $f(x,y) = \frac{x+1}x\frac{y+1}y$, one is looking for solutions to $f(a,c)=f(b,d)$.

Comment: This form of diophantine equation seems to be a generalization of the cycle problem in the unsolved Collatz Conjecture (see [Franco & Pomerance](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153499)). They deal with variants of Collatz sequences involving Crandall Numbers. Lets take the $181x+1$ sequence. There exist two corresponding $2$-cycles, namely $(27,611)$ and $(35,99)$. Such cycles exist if the diophantine equation given by OP is fullfilled: $(181\cdot27+1)(181\cdot611+1)\cdot35\cdot181\cdot99\cdot181=(181\cdot35+1)(181\cdot99+1)\cdot181\cdot27\cdot181\cdot611$.

Comment: Why $181x+1$? How did you obtain the the cycles? How do you obtian the link between the equation and the cycle problem?

Comment: @Jfischer  where did you get the problem?

Comment: @Jfischer: I sketched the connection to the Collatz Problem. Honestly I fear that no closed form exists, which works without factorization or bruteforce.

Comment: @WillJagy The problem arises from considerations on a Markov chain $X$ associate to a particle system on a finite graph $G$. It is not a textbook problem. Solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ give subgraphs of $G$ which are "of low energy" with respect to the stationary distribution of $X$.

Comment: @Jfischer  good. Please put that information in the question body somewhere. I hadn't thought this was homework, rather some sort of programming contest.  I made a quick program with $a > b,c,d > 0$ and then $ b \geq d,$   to prevent your    trivial cases and reduce repeats. Many solutions.    I could have relaxed to $a \geq c,$  $b \geq d,$  then $a >b,d$

Answer (score 1):

***Not an answer*** but a note about the connection with cycles that are subject to the so far unsolved Collatz problem:

Let us define the following function:

$$
g_k(x)=
\begin{cases}
kx+1 & 2\nmid x\\
x/2  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

In the case $k=3$ we have the so-called Collatz function and until now it is unproven whether a cycle exists other than the trivial one $(4,2,1,4,2,1,\ldots)$.

Interestingly there exist other $k$-values for which we can find such cycles. Crandall found for $k=5$ and $k=181$ such cycles. Let us take the example of $k=181$: There we have the two $2$-cycles $(27,611)$ and $(35,99)$, since $(181\cdot27+1)/2^3=611$ and $(181\cdot611+1)/2^{12}=27$.

If $g_k(x)$ contains such $2$-cycles, lets consider $(a,c)=(181\cdot27,181\cdot611)$ and $(b,d)=(181\cdot35,181\cdot99)$, then the diophantine equation given by the OP is fullfilled:

$$(a+1)\cdot(c+1)\cdot b\cdot d=(b+1)\cdot(d+1)\cdot a\cdot c\\=(181\cdot27+1)(181\cdot611+1)⋅35⋅181⋅99⋅181=(181⋅35+1)(181⋅99+1)⋅181⋅27⋅181⋅611$$

The case $k=5$ even exhibits $3$-cycles, see the work of [Crandall](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2006353) and [Franco and Pomerance](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153499). In the case of $3$-cycles the diophantine equation contains six variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

***Bruteforce workaround*** may help in the case that there is no explicit solution. At least we are able to collect all solutions by distinguishing two cases which I obtained by:

```
Reduce[a (b + 1) c (d + 1) == (a + 1) b (c + 1) d && a > 0 && b > 0
 && c > 0 && d > 0, {a, b, c, d}, Integers]
```

The first case is:

$$0<b<a\land 0<c<\frac{-a b-b}{b-a}\land d=\frac{-a b c-a c}{-a b+a c-b c-b}$$

and the second case is:

$$b\geq a\land d=\frac{-a b c-a c}{-a b+a c-b c-b}$$

Let us now generate solutions for the first case, for example up to $a=50$:

```
a_max=50
for a in range(1,a_max+1):
    for b in range(1,a):
        for c in range(1,(-b-a*b)//(-a+b)):
            num = -a*c-a*b*c
            denom = -b-a*b+a*c-b*c
            d = num // denom
            if num == d * denom:
                print([a,b,c,d])
```

Some solutions we get in this first case are:

```
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 8]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 4, 9]
[3, 2, 5, 15]
[3, 2, 6, 27]
[3, 2, 7, 63]
[4, 2, 2, 4]
...
[4, 3, 13, 104]
[4, 3, 14, 224]
[5, 2, 2, 5]
...
[50, 49, 2495, 1559375]
[50, 49, 2496, 2080000]
[50, 49, 2497, 3121250]
[50, 49, 2498, 6245000]
```

For the second case we can collect solutions for example up to $b=50$ and $c=50$ as follows:

```
b_max=50
c_max=50

for b in range(1,b_max+1):
    for a in range(1,b+1):
        for c in range(1,c_max):
            num = -a*c-a*b*c
            denom = -b-a*b+a*c-b*c
            d = num // denom
            if num == d * denom:
                print([a,b,c,d])
```

Some tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ retrieved for this second case are:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 3, 3]
...
[1, 1, 17, 17]
...
[50, 50, 48, 48]
[50, 50, 49, 49]
```

These are those solutions where $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Comment: I think there is a mix up of different notions of cycles? If I use the first one using $g_{181}(27)$ I get, iteratively applying $g_{181}$, the sequence, $27,4888,2444,1222,611,..$ . The second sens would be in the sence of the $C_q(m)$ from the publication, $C_{181}(27),C_{181}(C_{181}(27)), C_{181}(C_{181}(C_{181}(27)))$ which would indeed give $611,27,611$ and, therefore, a $2$ cycle. So I assume that you mean the latter. I am still trying to work out how you get that the diophantine equation is satisfied.

Comment: @Jfischer: The proof for the connection between between cycles and this diophantine equation is [here](https://github.com/Sultanow/collatz/blob/master/01%20Graph%20Theory/TeX/v6.0/algebrabook.pdf) on page 34-35.

Comment: Equation (4.4) in the cited text is always true?

Comment: Yes it is true for all cycles. Unfortunatelly there exist only few cycles - they are really rare. A more generalized approach for those cycles is descibed [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2673-9909/2/1/5) and a notebook is implemented [here](https://github.com/Sultanow/collatz/blob/master/04%20Cycles/Python/notebook/eldar_parityvector.ipynb).

Comment: Still trying to figure out why (4.4) in your link is true for cycles. In general, the text is very hard to read and does not necessarily correspond to mathematical standarts. Definitions do not contain definitions, new terminology is introduced in the text and theorems are somewhat losely integrated. I spend the afternoon trying to understand the structure and I would love to use the results but I just can't. Thank you, nonetheless, for the work you put in there.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this down and I know it can be done better and am also seriously interested in improving this. The correctness of 4.4 - I am very sure about that. Could you imagine to support me to reformulate this (we can go through this and write this together up as a mini-paper)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134615/discussion-between-jfischer-and-eldar-sultanow).